# JavaFX application over another fullscreen program on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I've been working on MacOS for some weeks now, I noticed that applications can't be overlapped over fullscreen applications.

**BUT** is there actually a way to change the properties of a `stage` in my case the `primaryStage` to overlap it over a fullscreen program, e.g. over Firefox or is this `os`sided not possible?

**I have tried:**

```
primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Which is always on top of non fullscreen applications, but I am not able to drag it over fullscreen applications.

Any idea?
**Plain code:**

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Simply giving the non-fullscreen window focus makes it appear on top of the fullscreen window for me on Windows 10. Can you do what you want with _any_ application on MacOS? If not, this may simply be platform dependent behavior.

Comment: @Slaw I guess it's really platform dependent and that there's no proper solution for it